# whats wrong with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I want that on pressing submit button, if the input was not correct(i.e. only letters) than warning(id="fn_warn") becomes vissible, but the code is not working. I think their is problem with getElementById.
Function isAlpha checks whether the value is letters only or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  First name
        <input id="first_name" type="text"/>
            <p id="fn_warn" style=" visibility: hidden; color: red;">#Please enter a valid name...</p>


          <input class="button" onclick="validate();" type="submit" value="Submit" />
          <input class="button" type="reset" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>

function validate(){
var submit=false;
var x = document.getElementById("first_name");
if (isAplha(x.value)){
    submit=true;
} else {
    var y = document.getElementById("fn_warn");
    y.style.visibility = "visible";
}
}

function isAlpha(value){
if (value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? You got the name of the "isAlpha" function wrong in the "validate" function; if it is really like that in your code it would generate an error. Also, what is the purpose of the "submit" variable? If it's to control whether the form is submitted, that just won't work. You have to return `false` from the "validate" function to prevent the default action.

Comment: @Pointy please vote to close as typo, then.

Comment: After correcting to isAlpha, in chrome the txt just blink for a moment and again becomes hidden. how can i solve that??

Comment: @ABCoder Ask a new question (and close this one).

Comment: @JanDvorak well other text in the question suggested that the code actually did something.

Comment: @ABCoder your "validate" function has to `return false` to prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: the point is not to submit the form... this is just some part of my code and quite simplified.. but the problem still persists

Comment: I suggest to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+prevent+form+submission . And FYI, *"but the code is not working"* is the least helpful problem description you could possibly give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend two things: fixing your typo for your first `if` statement that says `isAplha` instead of `isAlpha` and, if that doesn't fix it, checking your browser's console for errors, which is always a good idea when you're working with JS.

Comment: there are no errors in browser console, but the text just blinks for a moment after pressing submit, and again becomes hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You have "isAphla(x.value)" instead of isAlpha